# I want to add and minus year on click in php

Tags: php, date

This my code.

```
/*******************************PHP CODE*****************************************/
if(isset($_GET['date'])){ //
    $date = $_GET['date']; 
    $date = date('Y', strtotime($date));
}
else{
    $tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
    $date = date("Y", $tomorrow);
}


/*************************************************************************/
<table width="214" height="78" border"0">
    <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="10"><a href="?date=<?= date("Y", strtotime($date .'-1 year')) ?>"  title="Previous Day" >Previous Year</a></td>

    <td width="95" colspan="2"><a href="?date=<?= date("Y", strtotime($date . '+1 year')) ?>" title="Next Day" >Next Year</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="12" align="center"></td></tr>
</table>

/***********************************************************/
```

It is working but if I press NEXT year it will take me to 2013 and then I press
'PREVIOUS Year' it take me to 2011 instead of 2012.

Comment: I don't see you saving the date somewhere when you click Next Year?

Comment: Try to `echo` and see what value is being passed in the `$_GET` in php.

Comment: when i click on <a> tag it is sending Year to URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting too crazy with these date functions when all you're working with is year numbers.

```
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
$date = date("Y", $tomorrow);
```

This is identical to simply:

```
$date = date("Y");
```

And `$tomorrow` doesn't make sense there, you're just getting the current date in a long winded way. You also have some confusing stuff here:

```
<a title="Next Day">Next Year</a>
```

And this:

```
date("Y", strtotime($date . '+1 year'))
```

Is the same as simply `$date + 1`.

Also if you use strtotime, make sure not to mash things together. `strtotime($date .'-1 year')` comes out as something like `strtotime('2012-1 year')` which will not work, put a space before the minus symbol if you must use this approach.

I think this might be what you're after if you're just working with years:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $date = $_GET['date']; 
} else {
    $date = date("Y"); // current year
}
?>
```

```
<a href="?date=<?= $date - 1 ?>">Previous Year</a></td>
<a href="?date=<?= $date + 1 ?>">Next Year</a></td>
```

Comment: I want add and Minus year..! which i am getting form URL
LIKE BELOW
http://67.248.52.176/devm/calendar/yearlyView.php?date=2012

Comment: Its not working properly

Comment: You should rename your variables to be less confusing. For instance `$date` should be `$year`.